# create own svn repository hosting

Tags: svn, repository, project-hosting

Since a week I use *ToirtoiseSVN* and *AnkhSVN* and **GoogleCode** and **sourceforge.net** as my project hosting. For me it's frustrating to fill all this forms before create next project. So I start thinking about my own repository hosting.

Can I use simple file hosting etc. and install there software like use Google or SourceForge to have my own SVN Server? My point is to have independent repository in internet without all this uselessly UI interface which give me Google and SF to administrate my version control. I don't want to take advantage of already existing hosting services like GoogleCode etc. - I want to be independent from them! ;)

Or maybe it's other way to do **my own repository hosting** and **FREE** ;)  Please don't tell me that I'm at mercy of commercial hosting... :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) server is the easiest to get up and running

Comment: VisualSVN is something like Tortoise? what is difference between them ?

Comment: I just thinking to upload my project on hosting and if I don't have with me my laptop I just download project with svn... sorry if it's stupid! it's just my thought since using Tortoise...

Comment: you would interact the same way as you would with google code

Comment: I missed the SHARED portion of @Pekka answer. A shared hosting environment could be a problem.

Comment: @dr. Thanks for the recommendation. Will my code online be in a private repository that is accessible to a few users or will it be a public repo and will my code be publicly visible to anyone?

Comment: That's up to you. You set the read/write privileges in VisualSVN. Whether it is accessible over the internet depends on whether the IP you assign VisualSVN is just a local IP, a public IP, or a local IP mapped to public IP.

Answer (score 3):

It is very easy to set up a simple subversion repository, especially if it just for you. Actually, if it is just for you, you may set up a svn repository on local disk and you do not have to setup any server. I do that sometimes for my own little projects, just to have the history of my work.

Assuming you are on Unix, you create a repository with:

`svnadmin create /path/to/repo`

and checkout with:

`svn checkout file:///path/to/repo`

Plus just a little configuration:-). Let me know if you need more details on this kind of setup.

Comment: I see that this is solution for local repository? Your commands are equal to TortoiseSVN option "Create repository here" ?

Comment: Yes, they are equal. If you are on Windows and need a repository just for yourself, creating/accessing it with TortoiseSVN like this should work nicely for you. And zero more configuration in case of Windows:).

Answer (score 1):

You can't install subversion on a standard shared web hosting package. You will need either specialized hosting that explicitly provides subversion, or rent a small (possibly virtual) server and install all the software you need on that (the most flexible solution, but also requires quite a bit of knowledge to set up securely).

Also, check out my recent question on serverfault: [Affordable combined Ruby/Rails/Redmine + Subversion hosting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128618/affordable-combined-ruby-rails-redmine-subversion-hosting)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your own server, then you can simply follow a tutorial for whatever os.

I have ubuntu server and followed this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion

Comment: I unfortunately have only laptop. No 24/7 server :/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a distributed version control system like Mercurial or Git. With these systems you simply create a local repository to work against.

For backup/remote access you simply upload the folder to a web storage.

Comment: I use only TortoiseSVN as a client, so could you explain me what is difference to use Mercurial? I install it local and use like tortoise?

Comment: @netmajor: Yes, there is both a TortoiseHg http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/ and TortoiseGit http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/

Answer (score 0):

Setting up VisualSVN, like @dr suggested, would require your own windows server to install it on (ie a cheap VPS). You can get svn running on linux and linux vps are event cheaper than windows so shouldn't be too much of a financial burden if you want to go this route.

If you want pure free, then I feel unfortunatly you will have to stick with filling out forms :-)

Comment: For student VPS it's too much :/ Filling form or local repo is only free solution...

Comment: The other option is to run the repo internally in your house on a different machine. When I was a student we use to have at least 1 spare machine on in the house somewhere all the time. Maybe you can go that route? You can then setup a nightly backup which backs up your repos to gmail http://bit.ly/7HsXHM